# Generate timestamp for certain date next month

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I need to generate a timestamp for an exact date in the next month.

I want to generate the timestamp for the 10th of the next month automatically.

I tried playing around with strtotime but couldn't work it out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-10'). '+1 month'));
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you very much :)